# Enabling Azure Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, azure-virtual-machine

I accidentally turned off Remote Desktop access on a VM instance in Azure. Is there a way that I can turn RDP access back on through the portal, PowerShell, etc. ?

Comment: This is a better fit for ServerFault, as it's not a programming question.

Comment: Sort of related In my case I setup the inbound ports correctly, but I am running linux and forgot to install an interface. it is relatively easy

SSH in or use the serial console and type CMD
install a user interface and RDP and start it. here is my code


sudo apt-get install lxde -y
sudo apt-get install xrdp -y
/etc/init.d/xrdp start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start your VM on the portal, follow these steps

1. Select the VM, go to the dashboard
2. Click on the Endpoints tab and choose RDP from the list of endpoints provided
3. Once the RDP is selected, it gives you the default port number, use as is and save changes
   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Start your VM, then you can RDP your VM.

Enabling RDP using Powershell, check the below link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2013/10/26/remote-powershell-in-azure-iaas-virtual-machines.aspx
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-enable-remote-desktop/

Hope this helps

Girish Prajwal